# VS Code throwing error 'No package for import' but code compiles and runs fine

Tags: go, go-modules

As a work requirement learning `gRPC` through an online course.

I have a project defined in folder `greet` (outside of `GOPATH`) with three packages called:

- `greet_client`
- `greet_server`
- `greetpb`

[image]

In the `go.mod` file at the root of my project, I've specified the following:

```
module example.com/myuser/myproject

go 1.14
```

The code in `greet_server/server.go` makes a reference to `greetpb`.

I'm referencing it like the following:

[image]

I'm able to run `server.go` successfully.
It returns the expected the result:
[image]

My question is on the red squiggly lines VSCode throws saying it could not import greetpb:
[image]

Here's how package `greetpb` is defined (it's an auto generated file):
[image]

How can I get rid of this warning message?
Is it something I've not setup properly?

Update:

When I try to `ctrl+click` to view the module `greetpb` on the file `server.go`, I note that it's pointing to the url `pkg.go.dev`.

How can I make the program to do a "local" lookup?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late at the party but just in case someone has a similar issue.

What worked for after lots of tries was to edit the file
`~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

At the line that says I made it like this.
`"go.goroot": "../",`

In this project everything was in the one level out. For now it's ok.

Just a diclaimer, I am new to Go. So I will edit in future in case I learn something new about this.

Answer (score -1):

1. Why would you use `example.com`? You don't have your package defined there.
2. Initialize go modules first i.e.

`go mod init github.com/$USER/$REPO`

3. Go mod vendor

`go mod tidy && go mod vendor`

4. That's it.

Comment: `example.com` is fine for a test module that isn't published anywhere. `go mod vendor` is also not necessary.

Comment: Also they've already initialized the module, as you can tell by the presence of `go.mod` and `go.sum` files